# 'TypeError: props.todoList is undefined' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im creating a simple app using the FARM(Fast API,React, MongoDB). I was following a tutorial on YT(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzUzrs8uJl8). Ive been trying to solve this problem for the last day but no luck, if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated, thanks

*Todo.js*

```
import axios from "axios"
import React from "react"

function TodoItem(props) {
    const deleteTodoHandler = (title) => {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/api/todo/${title}').then(res =>console.log(res.data))}
        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold, underline'}}>{props.todo.title} : </span> {props.todo.description}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTodoHandler(props.todo.title)}
                    className="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 mx-2" style= {{'borderRadius':'50px',}}>X</button>
                    <hr></hr>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
}

export default TodoItem;
```

*TodoListView.js*

```
import TodoItem from "./Todo"

 function TodoView(props) {
     return (

         <div>
             <ul>
                {props.todoList.map(todo => <TodoItem todo= 
                {todo} />)}
             </ul>
         </div>
     )
 }
export default TodoView
```

p.s. if its a syntax error im sorry

Comment: When you console.log(props) in the TodoView what do you see then?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
props.todoList
```

here `todoList` is coming from axios call and which is an async call and the data is not available on first render and you are trying to access some data which is not available that's why the error.

So use a [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) like:

```
{
  ( props.todoList && props.todoList.length > 0 )
  ?
  props.todoList.map(todo => <TodoItem todo={todo} />)
  :
  null
}
```

Comment: @imsobadatcoding If this is the most suitable answer, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027611) the answer by clicking the check mark